# Making my header "fixed" resizes the header-box

Tags: html, css

I want to make a fixed-header, with the clickable links on the left and our logo on the right.

No issues with floating the text + image to it's corresponding place and to make the header take up the whole width of the screen. Once I make it "fixed" the header's width shrinks to the width of the 3 links I have added.

The width of the header is already set to 100% and I cannot seem to find what the underlying issue is

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

header {
  width 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 999;
}

footer {
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: bold;
}

header ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 60px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

header ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header ul a:hover {
  color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
}

.thumb-container {
  max-width: calc(960px + 40px);
  margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
}

.thumb-container a {
  width: calc(960px / 3);
  height: calc(960px / 3);
  background: aqua;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .thumb-container {
    max-width: 660px;
    /* in midden zetten */
    background: black;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .thumb-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    /* in midden zetten */
    background: black;
  }
  .thumb-container a {
    width: 100%;
    /* maakt containers volledige  breedte*/
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">  Benodigdheden </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Over ons </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <img src="img/" alt="lol">

</header>

<main>

  <div class="thumb-container">

    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>

    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>



</main>


<footer> Test footer text</footer>
```

Comment: To be honest there are more issues with your html/css that nobody points out, I would recommend checking my answer for a more valid and descriptive answer on what it is and how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a ":" for the width property.
Kindly correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">Benodigdheden</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He is just missing a ":" when setting his width ;) but nicer and cleaner solution to his/her problem - upvoted

Comment: Yeah ! actually

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ":" when setting your width!

It should be `width: 100%;` not `width 100%;`

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 999;
}

footer {
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: bold;
}

header ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 60px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

header ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header ul a:hover {
  color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
}

.thumb-container {
  max-width: calc(960px + 40px);
  margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
}

.thumb-container a {
  width: calc(960px / 3);
  height: calc(960px / 3);
  background: aqua;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .thumb-container {
    max-width: 660px;
    /* in midden zetten */
    background: black;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .thumb-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    /* in midden zetten */
    background: black;
  }
  .thumb-container a {
    width: 100%;
    /* maakt containers volledige  breedte*/
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">  Benodigdheden </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Over ons </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <img src="img/" alt="lol">

</header>

<main>

  <div class="thumb-container">

    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>

    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>



</main>


<footer> Test footer text</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by setting the property `right: 0;`. If you look at my example I would recommend you that you remove the `float: left;` and use `display: flex;` instead. I changed your example to reflect what I mean. Hope this helps.

I recommend you to look at this post and video

- [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Wes Bos (it is free)](https://flexbox.io/)

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.header__logo {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.navigation-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navigation-links__link {
  margin-left: 60px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.navigation-links__link a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-links__link a:hover {
  color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
}

footer {
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.thumb-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: calc(960px + 40px);
  margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
}

.thumb-container a {
  width: calc(960px / 3);
  height: calc(960px / 3);
  background: aqua;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .thumb-container {
    max-width: 660px;
    /* in midden zetten */
    background: black;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .thumb-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    /* in midden zetten */
    background: black;
  }
  .thumb-container a {
    width: 100%;
    /* maakt containers volledige  breedte*/
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation-links">
      <li class="navigation-links__link"> <a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
      <li class="navigation-links__link"> <a href="#">  Benodigdheden </a></li>
      <li class="navigation-links__link"> <a href="#"> Over ons </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!--<img src="img/" alt="lol" class="header__logo">-->
  <div class="header__logo"></div>

</header>

<main>

  <div class="thumb-container">

    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <a href="#"> </a>

  </div>



</main>


<footer> Test footer text</footer>
```

Comment: he is just missing a ":" tho ^^

Comment: @DigitalJedi I noticed that, I tend to use `right: 0;`. I also took the time to point out other issues with the code, like the absence of a clearfix when using floats (which can cause width issues as well), it being 2019 I rather recommend using flex then floats. One of the issues with SO is people just try to collect points rather then taking time to point out and help people.